# How to find Windows Script Host languages installed

Tags: scripting, asp-classic, wsh

How do I find out what WSH (Active Scripting) languages are installed on a machine?

I know that JScript and VBScript are installed by default, but how do I find out if, for example, Python is installed for WSH?

Comment: You could always just try running an asp page which uses Python.  Practically speaking though support for PerlScript and Python was provided if you installed the ActiveState distributions of Perl and Python respectively. As far as I know ActiveState's current versions  no longer include these, so I'd say it's pretty safe to assume that you're restricted to JS and VBS.

Comment: @John Yes, I tried running Python script but apparently Python is not installed on my machine as WSH engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Turns out that `regedit` comes handy here. If you search for all `OLEScript` keys under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`, you will find their parent class IDs.

You can then identify the DLLs that implement the installed scripting engines (e.g. jscript.dll, vbscript.dll) by looking at the corresponding `InprocServer32` keys under each class ID.

I suspect that's what TC (described below) is doing.

**ORIGINAL**

I *initially* (see edit above) used [Take Command shell replacement](https://jpsoft.com/products/take-command.html) (thankfully, free 30 day trial) which has a `script` command that lists the installed scripting engines (I was surprised to find e.g. XML to be considered a scripting engine).

Not quite what I had in mind (requires a proprietary, 3rd party payware to be installed; quite pricey at $100) but it did allow me to answer my original question: what WSH scripting engines are installed.